# Progress bar for loading file

Tags: c++

Whenever I try to load big files my program doesn't show me anything until file loads and then it prints "loaded successfully" , But I want it to print that how many percent is loaded every 0.500ms (Its in c++) how can I get that how much of the file is loaded to convert it into the percents?

Comment: That'd depend on what sort of file you're loading and what you're doing with it. If it's a CSV, pretty easy. If it's a PSD, even Photoshop doesn't give an accurate loading estimate.

Comment: A code sample would be helpful.

Comment: What does “loading” mean?  Are you manually reading bytes into a buffer?  What further processing is then required until you consider loading finished?

Comment: Show a small snippet of code, especially showing how you are loading the file.  For example, are you using threads?  Does the file loading function communicate with the GUI thread, and how?  When does the function communicate with the GUI thread?

Comment: Get the total size of your file.  Create a buffer that is 1% of that size.  Then every time you read part of the file into the buffer, add 1% to your progress.  This question has far too little information to provide a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to get the total bytes or lines that are in the file.  This will be the denominator when calculating the percentage.

If you use the file size, you may be able to calculate the percentage by using the file read position.

The recommended algorithm is to use at least two threads.
One thread is the GUI thread.
The other thread is the worker thread.  The worker thread will be reading in the file.

Some people believe that the worker thread should post it's progress to a global variable and the GUI thread should poll that variable.

Other people believe that the worker thread should post messages to the GUI thread at periodic or other intervals.

The choice is yours.